# Java: Re-use ports before linux OS puts them into TIME_WAIT

Tags: java, sockets, server

I am trying to build a java multi threaded server using a thread pool. I have limited the number of threads to perform my actions to 15 but every time the server socket accepts a new connection it creates the connection on a new port, once the thread is complete it closes the socket however linux puts the port into a TIME_WAIT state. This server receives a lot of traffic and because of the wait it quickly runs out of available ports and hangs until the timed wait expires. I do not have root access to change the time wait time so is there a way to re-use ports instead of putting them into TIME_WAIT?

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception{
  init_LogServer.initMarshal();
  ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(44431);
  ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> transactionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String>();
  CountTrans Tracker = new CountTrans(transactionMap);
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
  System.out.println("Waiting...");
  //listen for log packets
  while(true){
    //open socket
    Socket connectionSocket = socket.accept();
    //send to thread
    Runnable worker = new LogThread(connectionSocket, Tracker);
    executor.execute(worker);
  }
}
```

Comment: It does not assign a new port. The accepted socket uses the same port as the listening socket.

Answer (score 1):

The way to stop TIME_WAITs piling up at the server is to be the one that *receives* the close first. That simply means that you should adjust your socket handling code to loop, instead of just processing a single request/response pair. When the client closes the socket, you will detect end of stream instead of a new request, close the socket, and exit the handler. Closing the socket after the client has already done so means that TIME_WAIT happens at the client end.

As another benefit, you can then implement connection-pooling at the client.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you can't change the TIME_WAIT time you can't change the TIME_WAIT time.

If you could, you might run into problems because the idea of the TIME_WAIT state is to stop any stray packets from this connection from interfering with the next connection.

I suppose you'll have to get another IP address or make less connections.

Comment: I know that there is a setReuseAddress(true) option. I don't think that it would work in this case as it's not the address that is being over used but the ports, is there anything comparable?

Comment: @nhoughto, right, that's for listening.  I'm fairly certain there isn't anything like that for accepted connections.